# Daterangepicker input field is not 24-hours-format

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I use daterangepicker 2.1.17.

When i use 24-hours format, it changes only the time picker in the selection pop-up menu but in the input field it is still not in AM/PM format (the only difference is AM/PM is not visible)

my html:

```
<input class="date-ranger-label" id="drp" name="daterange-filter-date-f"/>
```

js :

```
$(drp).daterangepicker({
    locale : {
        format : 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm',
        "separator" : " > "
    },
    "singleDatePicker" : true,
    "showDropdowns" : true,
    "showWeekNumbers" : true,
    "timePicker" : true,
    "drops": "up",
    "timePicker24Hour" : true,
    "autoApply" : true,
}, function (a, b, c) {
    cbFunction(a, b, c);
});
```

For example, if i select 14.25 and click on okay, i see 02.25 in the input field. How can that be translated to 24-hours format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe it was so simple and tricky.

```
locale : {
        format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH/MM'
    }
```

So, just hours and date string in upper case.

*By the way, i'm wondering why such a thing is not contained in documentation or tutorials.*

Answer (score 0):

locale.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'.
Daterangepickerjs used momentjs, refer to [http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/]